# How to know if I have activated Cloudfare successfully?

Tags: cdn, cloudflare

I am using Siteground hosting and Cloudfare free CDN.

On cloudfare website I get this -

[image]

and on Siteground I get this -

[image]

I have updated the CNAME records as asked, several times.

[image]

Please guide me:
Is CDN active?
Is it correctly done?
How to remove the error and do it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

DNS changes usually take 24 to 48 hours to fully start working but it still doesn't work, perhaps you can use the [Cloudflare Diagnostic Center](https://www.cloudflare.com/fr-fr/diagnostic-center/). I also found [this tool](https://checkforcloudflare.selesti.com/) that check if your website is using Cloudflare DNS / CDN/Proxy / SSL. Otherwise, there is a [similar topic on their forum](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/how-do-i-know-its-working-properly/13952/2) that explain how to verify it using http headers.

Comment: https://checkforcloudflare.selesti.com/?q=maidinthemidlands.co.uk  on this it says not using  DNS

Comment: Did you open a ticket on Cloudflare and/or your DNS provider ?